# Rounding several columns on SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am able to Round a single column on SQL:

```
 SELECT CUST_NAME, ROUND(opening_amnt,0) AS RoundedAmount
 FROM Customer_110385461;
```

However I do not know how to round up several columns at once? I tried

```
 SELECT CUST_NAME, ROUND(opening_amnt,0)(receive_amnt,0) AS RoundedAmount
 FROM Customer_110385461;
```

But I received the error "too many arguments to function".

Comment: If you seperate your 2 rounded values as so: SELECT CUST_NAME, ROUND(opening_amnt,0), ROUND(receive_amnt,0)
 FROM Customer_110385461; What does it look like?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CUST_NAME
  , ROUND(opening_amnt,0) as Rounded_Opening_Amnt
  , ROUND(receive_amnt,0) AS Rounded_Receive_Amnt
FROM Customer_110385461;
```

If you want them added or something prior to that, then you would do that inside a single round function.

Comment: If i had 3 columns would it be ROUND(OPENING_AMNT,0,RECEIVE_AMNT,0,OTHERAMT,0)

Comment: no, you would do 3 separate columns, ROUND can only round a single value passed to it.